# Transforming integral to polar coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-transforms

By transforming to polar coordinates, show that

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)} \,dy\,dx$$

Is equal to

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\log(\sqrt{2}\cos(\theta))}{\cos(2\theta)} d\theta$$

I have tried the standard $x=r\cos(\theta)$ etc. And can easily see that the limits for theta is $0,\pi/4$ with a sketch. However, I'm struggling to compute the integral that comes out, which ranges $r$ from $r=0$ to $r=\frac{1}{\cos{\theta}}$. Also, I can integrate this explicitly using tan substitution but does that help?

Comment: any hints or progress?

Comment: So is it true you have been explicitly asked to first transform the double integral using polar coordinates before evaluating it?

Comment: no, i was asked first to evaluate it the nice way, and secondly to use polar coordinates

Comment: I see. So the "nice" way is definitely how I did it below. As for the transformation to polar coordinates, see @DavidG answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have correctly converted the region of integration and thus we have:

\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_1^{\sec(\theta)} \frac{1}{\left(1 + r^2\cos^2(\theta)\right)\left(1 + r^2\sin^2(\theta)\right)} \cdot r\:dr\:d\theta \\
\end{align}

Applying a [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) we arrive at:
\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_1^{\sec(\theta)} \frac{1}{\left(1 + r^2\cos^2(\theta)\right)\left(1 + r^2\sin^2(\theta)\right)} \cdot r\:dr\:d\theta \\ 
&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_1^{\sec(\theta)} \frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)}\left[\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{1 + r^2\cos^2(\theta)} - \frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{1 + r^2\sin^2(\theta)} \right] r\:dr\:d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)}\int_1^{\sec(\theta)}\left[\frac{r\cos^2(\theta)}{1 + r^2\cos^2(\theta)} - \frac{r\sin^2(\theta)}{1 + r^2\sin^2(\theta)} \right]\:dr\:d\theta \\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\ln\left|1 + r^2\cos^2(\theta) \right| + \ln\left|1 + r^2\sin^2(\theta) \right| \bigg]_1^{\sec(\theta)} \:d\theta
\end{align}

You okay from here?

**Edit**: The rest of the solution:

\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\ln\left|1 + r^2\cos^2(\theta) \right| + \ln\left|1 + r^2\sin^2(\theta) \right| \bigg]_1^{\sec(\theta)} \:d\theta \\
&=  \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\ln(2) + \ln\left|\sec^2(\theta) \right| \bigg] \:d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1}{\cos(2\theta)}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|2\sec^2(\theta)\right|\:d\theta\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\ln\left| \sqrt{2}\sec(\theta)\right|}{\cos(2\theta)}\:d\theta
\end{align}

Comment: I suspect that you intended the lower limit of the inside integral to be $\sec(0)$ instead of $0$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales - Yes, thank you for the correction. I will edit now.

Comment: @Dis-integrating - They don't have to be constants to apply a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to substitute r^2 = u

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have to transform this double integral first using polar coordinates? It is far easier to just integrate it as is. Here
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_0^x \frac{dy \, dx}{(1 + x^2)(1 + y^2)} &= \int_0^1 \left [\frac{\tan^{-1} y}{1 + x^2} \right ]_0^x \, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1} x}{1 + x^2} \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \big{[} (\tan^{-1} x)^2 \big{]}_0^1\\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{32}
\end{align}

Comment: Indeed. I believe it is meant to be via polar coordinates as the first words of the post "By transforming to polar coordinates, show that" reads very much like a textbook styled problem. 

Not saying it's a homework problem though.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the OP thought, from the integrands form, conversion to polar coordinates was the way to go thereby overlooking a direct approach. I will ask for clarification.

Comment: i mean i admit its a problem i was assigned but there were two parts. I can't see a way to use this to solve the latter though

Answer (score 0):

Or even easier than omegadot's argument, note this is the $x\ge y$ half of $\left(\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}\right)^2$, i.e. $\frac{(\pi/4)^2}{2}=\frac{\pi^2}{32}$.